# Calculating stock per day

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400

In my report http://pastebin.com/HJJBCueY
I would like to add another column named "Stock per day" that will store
sum of all stock values per day . 
For all rows IN 05.06.2013 that column would have value=110221, and for all rows 88777. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To get the total stock per day:

```
SELECT DATA, SUM(STOCK) AS "Stock per day" FROM table_name
GROUP BY DATA
```

Comment: Yeah right, but in query I'm already using group by DATA,COLOR
I was thinking about using  OVER and PARTITION BY 




    SELECT t.data,t.color,t.stock, SUM(t.stock) OVER(partition by  t.data order by t.data) as "stock per day"
    FROM t